# Disabling online video playing ability of Windows 10 run PC

Tags: windows-10, command-line, drivers, software-rec

How to disable the online video playing ability of Windows 10 OS? SO that it can not play videos online like videos on facebook or any other website but it can play downloaded videos.

Comment: This would have to be a feature of the browser, not the operating system,  I believe Chrome and Firefox both recently added this feature.  Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: Is there any kind of driver which is responsible for playing videos online?

Comment: No; A video that starts automatically is done within the code of the website.  Certain browsers have gone to the effort to block videos from automatically starting.  There are also browser plugins that will accomplish that task.  However, questions seeking software recommendations, are out of scope here at Super User

Answer (score 0):

Aside from very dirty solutions already posted, which also disable local playback, this is impossible. Videos are streaming via port 80 or 443 on a computer and you can't block those without losing access to websites.

The more sensible solution here would be a browser addon that blocks video or simply and ad blocker. There are several options out there, try them at your leisure.

The other method would be to use a stateful inspection firewall and disallow certain remote hosts like YouTube to discourage streaming.

Comment: The reason I was asking this question was because I am addicted to porn. I want to get rid of this problem and rewire my brain. Whenever, I need to use internet, I am prompted to watch porn which is causing problem in my recovery problem. I know disabling video streaming capability isn't the ultimate solution but the problem is so acute and my exams are going on I would like to disable the option in my PC temporarily. So that I can focus on my studies now and later on when I am recovered from this addiction I may get back the feature. Besides, it is also important to use net for my study.

Comment: You need a filter. There are many of these available.

Comment: But If I use a filter I can then remove it and watch porn again in no time. My problem is acute and I need some time. @music2myear

Comment: There are filters that break the system if they are removed without a password held by a third party. Even your disabling of video playback can be easily disabled/worked around. You're fixated on a specific solution and blind to the fact that it has more pitfalls than other solutions. I wish you well in your struggle, but you NEED to recognize that your desired solution is NOT a solution.

Comment: @MohiburRahman Use a child filter in your network. This will remove those sites for you. Have a friend set the password and tell them not to give you the password for a specific amount of time. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You all with your answers. And I am going to use child filter and have set the password by a friend @TuxStash.de